# Using texmaker to run Tex Live headless on Debian 10

Tags: texlive, texmaker, debian

Since i have a Debian 10 Server running in the basement, i'd like to use it to compile .tex files. To have the advantages of using e.g. apt to update tex live, i'd prefer not to install the tex live packages in a shared folder (netinstall) - or i don't understand how to do it right.

So what i basically want, is to open a .tex file stored in a shared folder on the server with my old (windows) laptop, edit the .tex document, say in texmaker or notepad++, and hit some button to let the server compile the file and put the .pdf file in the same directory as the .tex file.

Doing the last step over ssh should't be a big problem, but how to integrate this funcionality in texmaker or get texmaker to use an ssh shell..?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I think you'll need to run TeXMaker on your Linux box so that it can run TeX without problems, capture its output, etc. Under this assumption, you need to run TeXMaker on the Linux box but display its window(s) on your Windows box. This can be done with X11 forwarding via `ssh`. See [How to use X11 forwarding with PuTTY](https://superuser.com/q/119792) for instance.

Comment: Great, thanks for your suggestion!